# Serializing custom IEnumerable<T> as field not working

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I have a custom collection that looks like this:

```
class SpecialReadOnlyCollection<T> : IReadOnlyCollection<T>{
    private readonly List<T> entries;
    public SpecialReadOnlyCollection(IEnumerable<T> source){
        entries = new List<T>(source);
    }
    ...
}
```

That (among other things) wraps a list but doesn't offer an `Add` method.

Now I have two other classes:

```
class A{
    public string Name;
    public int Value;
}

class ContainerOfA{
    public SpecialReadOnlyCollection<A> list;

    public ContainerOfA(IEnumerable<A> source){
        this.list = new SpecialReadOnlyCollection<A>(source);
    }
}
```

I want to serialize a `ContainerOfA`. Since I don't like attributes, this is how I build the model and try to serialize.

```
    // Make A serializable
var metaType = Model.Add(typeof(A),true);
metaType.AddField(1,"Name");
metaType.AddField(2,"Value");
metaType.UseConstructor = false;

// Make SpecialCollection serializable
Model.Add(typeof(SpecialReadOnlyCollection<A>),true).AddField(1,"entries");
Model[typeof(SpecialReadOnlyCollection<A>)].IgnoreListHandling = true;
Model[typeof(SpecialReadOnlyCollection<A>)].UseConstructor = false;

// Make container serializable
Model.Add(typeof(ContainerOfA),true).AddField(1,"list");
Model[typeof(ContainerOfA)].UseConstructor = false; 

// Initialize the container
A a = new A{Name ="Name", Value =1};
A[] arr = {a};
var container = new ContainerOfA(arr);

// Try and serialize .... 
Model.DeepClone(container);
```

However, when I try to serialize, I get an exception:

```
Unable to resolve a suitable Add method for SpecialReadOnlyCollection[A]
```

What I find weird is that if I try to serialize just the list it works fine:

```
Model.DeepClone(container.list);
```

Everything works fine as well if I instead of building the model in code use attributes. In fact, everything works if I use attributes only in `ContainerOfA` and make `A` and the `SpecialReadOnlyCollection` serializable via code.

Is there something I am doing wrong? How can I get around this? (Probably the easiest answer is to use attributes ... but I really want to avoid attributes).

tl;dr: How to, via `RuntimeTypeModel`, use protobuf-net serialize a class that has as a member an IEnumerable that should not be treated as a list (`IgnoreListHandling = true`).

Answer (score 0):

protobuf-net supports a range of list patterns; in your case, it is trying to use the `IEnumerable<T>/GetEnumerator()` and `Add(T)` pattern. It needs *both* of those things: the `IEnumerable<T>/GetEnumerator()` is used for serialization, and the `Add(T)` is used for deserialization. If your custom collection does not have an obvious `Add(T)` method, then protobuf-net will refuse to work with the collection, because *it won't ever be able to deserialize*. That is what the method is telling you.

The only way to get around this is probably with a mutable DTO model, rather than this read-only collection. There *are* things like implicit type conversions that protobuf-net supports, but not for this scenario.

Comment: So I think I am misunderstanding what `IgnoreListHandling` does. Doesn't that attribute tell protobuf that the class should be handled as a normal class instead of as a list?

What I find weird is that by decorating with attributes it works just fine. In fact, what seems to be problematic is the way I add `ContainerOfA` to the model, rather than the `IEnumerable` itself.

Comment: Moreso, serializing the list works fine as well. What makes it stop working is trying to serialize it as a field in some other object.

Comment: @SantiagoCerónUribe re the "field in some other object" - yeah, there's a slight difference in how root objects  are treated - not ideal, but: it only looks as far as the `IEnumerable<T>`. The `IgnoreListHandling` does indeed tell it to treat it as a leaf, not a list. It could be I've misunderstood the question: can I read it again tomorrow on a fresh night's sleep?

Comment: It could be (if you misunderstood then I still have hope!). Thank you very much for your fast help.

Comment: @SantiagoCerónUribe how would you feel about using a surrogate serialization type in place of `ContainerOfA`? i.e. a type that looks similar (but presumably with a `List<A>` field) that is automagically swapped backwards and forwards as needed? the library supports that usage. I can do an example tomorrow if that would suffice. From all outward appearances: you would be serializing / deserializing a `ContainerOfA`

Comment: I had thought about the surrogate, I was just finding it strange to see it work when using attributes, but getting some really weird behavior if using the `RuntimeTypeModel`. (For example, if `A` has a base class `B`, the schema will show `ContainerOfA` to have a list of `B`).

Would the surrogate have to be for `ContainerOfA` instead of for the actual collection then?

Comment: So, is there a workaround for this issue using RuntimeTypeModel or not? Because I have faced with the same issue and it does not work even if I am using Attributes.